# different applicationIds not resulting in side-by-side installs

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've been trying to build different product flavours to allow multiple side-by-side installs for our QA teams so I changed the `applicationId` to be different in each one.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationId = "com.mypackagename.qa"
        ....
    }

    release {
        applicationId = "com.mypackagename"
        ....
    }

    development {
        applicationId = "com.mypackagename.development
        ....
    }
}
```

However when I attempt to install them all, the release version is installed alone but both the development and the debug end up replacing each other.

Any thoughts on how to get them to install side by side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add versionNameSuffix. This is how it should look like:

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix ".dev"
            applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
        }
        iqa {
        versionNameSuffix ".IQA"
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        applicationIdSuffix '.IQA'
    }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```